# on submit form span message changes position why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to understand why the message generated by jquery it's changing position everytime a field gets empty!

So, if the message is generated by the feedback of ajax it's placed in the proper place which is right beneath the login box. If the field (input box) is empty on submit the ajax script is not called and the message of empty field it's shows right on but 40px or more beneath.

The jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        <!--
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#loginform").submit(function(){

                                $('#loginform input[type=text]').each(function(n,element){  
                                    if ($(element).val()=='') {
                                        $(".message").html('<p>O campo '+element.id+' tem de ter um valor!</p>').fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
                                        return false;  
                                    } 

                                    else{
                                        $.post("login.php", { usrname:$("#Nome").val(), passwd:$("#Palavra-passe").val()}, function(data){
                                            if(data == '1'){
                                                $("#subLog").hide();
                                                $(".message").html('<p>Login efectuado com sucesso, a redirecionar...</p>').fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function (){
                                                    $("#login").fadeOut('slow', function(){
                                                        location.reload();
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                $("#subLog").hide();
                                                $(".message").html('<p>Erro! Tente novamente por-favor!</p>').fadeIn("slow").delay(1500).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                                                    $("#subLog").fadeIn('fast');
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                                return false;
                            });
                        });
                        //-->
                        </script>
```

The css message style:

```
.message{
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    margin-top: 65px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
    border: 2px solid white;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

the form:

```
<div class="box" id="login" style="width: 326px; height: 228px; top: 39%; background-image: url('images/loginBox.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;">

<form id="loginform" action="" method="post">

    <fieldset style="display: block">
        <legend></legend>
            <input id="Nome" class="transparent" type="text">
        <input id="Palavra-passe" class="transparent" type="password"> 
        <input id="subLog" type="submit" value="Login">
    </fieldset>

</form>

<div class="message"></div>
```

UPDATE:

The submit button get's hidden when the ajax instruction is called therefore the position changes 65px. To correct this small problem I have removed the margin-top property from the css rule and changed the position with .css('margin-top', 'value'). This way I change the value to the different messages and both get displayed in the same screen position. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't know exactly how it looks after the ajax response, but if you leave the field empty you just need to take off this line from css

```
margin-top: 65px;
```

and it's ok.

look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ature/2/

P.S. i also added

```
$('div.message').hide();
```

to avoid having the div message display before any warning is generated

EDIT - maybe you have other rules affecting your div. if the other rules are loaded before you insert this you can add the line

```
margin-top: 0px;
```

to override them.

moreover: remeber to clear your cache when you reload yopur page!

Comment: I followed your advise and it didn't work! Both messages are now displaying 65px above...

Comment: And still not displaying in the same spot. :(

Comment: Have you taken a look at the fiddle?are you sure there are no other CSS rules that are affecting that div?

Comment: yes, and the message got displayed 65px above. And as you mentioned the ajax feedback It can't be showed but it's now being displayed in a different place... "-" 65px :(

Comment: well I got a lot of css rules but if they affect the div content in the first message they would affect the second message the same way I guess...

Comment: Ok, maybe i got you wrong, i thought your problem was that the message didn't appear (as it does in the fiddle) right below the submit button. where exactly do you want it?

Comment: If you want the message just above the submit button you must change the html like i did here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ature/3/

Comment: 65px form the top, the problem is that the ajax feedback is Ok and the empty field code instruction is displaying the .message 130px from the top... something wrong 65 + 65 = 130, so I guess something is wrong with the $('div.message').hide(); what you think?

Comment: I guess I found out the problem... can it be the button that gets hidden after submit right? And when empty the button doesn't get hidden! I'll check it out!